# redeclared symbol between class function and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, conflict

there are two header files in my makefile.

one has a function symbol "uint32_t util::hash(const char*)",

another has a namespace symbol "namespace util::hash { }"

g++ complains:

```
StringUtil.h:24: error: ‘uint32_t util::hash(const char*)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
../util/hash/Hash_Interface.h:8: error: previous declaration of ‘namespace util::hash { }’
```

and these two files are from other lib, so I can not change the name. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put one of the header file inclusions in a namespace, like

```
namespace foo
{
#include "some_file.h"
}
```

Now all symbols from the `"some_file.h"` header file are in the `foo` namespace.

Comment: @arne Neither would I, but if you have two external libraries both declaring the same namespace containing one or more symbols that exist in the other, then what are you going to do?

Comment: I know there's no other way. I just wanted to point out that this is something one should avoid when designing a library. Namespaces like `util` with functions like `hash` are just too generic.

Comment: This will probably fail, unless you can recompile the library to export its symbols in the new namespace. If you can do that, then you can fix the library properly.